# Only support iPad2

Tags: xcode, ipad, appsettings, ipad-2

I am making a app involve the use of camera. However, ipad1 does not support and crash when press the camera.

How can I choose that app only support ipad2 but not ipad1? 
Is there anything i can set in the setting or any code i can type in?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify device requirements in the [info.plist](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html)  You would just specify that it [needs a camera](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW3)